# How to convert std::array to std::string

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a small trouble in converting std::array to std::string.
I have something like that:

```
std::stringstream message;
message << 12345 << '\0' << '\0'
        << '\0' << "SOMETHING IMPORTANT" << '\0';
```

Next I'm using boost::asio::io::socket to send the `message.str()`
My server is receiving the message and saving it to `std::array<char, 1024>`, but the problem is that I can't extract just the "SOMETHING IMPORTANT".
I've tried to use `std::array.begin()` which returns only `12345`, I also tried std::array.data() which returns my data + a lot of junk. I believe it's not a hard task, but I got stuck on it.

Comment: The receiving side must know the format of the message and how to read it. Is it always 5 digits, 3 null characters and then a null terminated message? If so, you could read starting from 9th character till null terminator.

Comment: What you're asking is how to parse a message. You know the format, so ... just reverse it. You put a leading value and then three zeroes before the important bit, so you should skip the leading value and then three zeroes before trying to read the important bit. The details depend on the semantics of your format (ie, could there be other fields between the zeroes? Are there always three zeroes?) which you haven't described.

Comment: When server receives the message it also obtains amount of items read into array so you know where data ends and junk starts.

Comment: Note that, if you're using TCP, it's a stream-based protocol and you don't necessarily receive everything the other end sent in one go.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen but how can I start reading from 9th character till null terminator? Especially till null terminator bothers me, since the array size is 1024.

Comment: As an aside from my answer, you can also use `boost::asio::streambuf` and have tight integration with `istream`. It makes buffer management a lot easier (at the cost of some dynamic allocation etc)

Comment: @sehe could you elaborate on it? At this moment i have something like `std::array<char, 1024> data;
  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), (..)`

Comment: I think I was already quite elaborate in my answer :) I'd recommend per-using the documentation/examples (e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/sync_client.cpp) and come back with questions if you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is parsing.

In the literal sense of your question title, you would convert an array to string like this:

```
 std::array<char, 1024> buf;
 std::string value(buf.data(), bytes_transferred);
```

Where bytes_transferred is the known size of the data in the buffer (so you don't have to rely on `buf.size()`, which would always be 1024).

However, since you're basically parsing from a stream, you can use one:

```
 std::stringstream ss;
 ss.write(buf.data(), bytes_transferred);
```

And then you can use the stream as you would normally:

```
 unsigned n;
 ss >> n;
```

Or

```
 std::string important;
 std::getline(ss, 1024, '\0');
```

### Real Parsing

To take it to another level you might use a proper parser to convert the access of your buffer. E.g. using Boost Spirit:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jYsGev1TW)**

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

int main() {
    std::array<char, 1024> buf;
    size_t bytes_transferred;
    static constexpr char NUL = '\0';

    {
        std::stringstream message;
        message << 12345 << NUL << NUL << NUL << "SOMETHING IMPORTANT" << NUL
                << "trailing";

        // emulating the asio read:
        message.read(buf.data(), buf.size());
        bytes_transferred = message.gcount();
    }

    // now we can do the desired parsing:
    unsigned value;
    std::string important;

    auto bound_attributes = std::tie(value, important);
    auto f = begin(buf), l = f + bytes_transferred;

    if (x3::parse(f, l,
                  x3::uint_ >> NUL >> NUL >> NUL >> *~x3::char_(NUL) >> NUL,
                  bound_attributes)) {
        std::cout << "Sucessfully parsed message: " << value << " and "
                  << std::quoted(important) << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed to parse parse";
    }

    if (f != l) {
        auto bytes_remaining = std::distance(f,l);
        std::cout << "Remaining in buffer: " << bytes_remaining << " bytes\n";
        std::rotate(buf.begin(), f, l);      // put at front of buffer
        bytes_transferred = bytes_remaining; // just for example

        std::cout << "Buffer contents: "
                  << std::quoted(std::string(buf.begin(), bytes_remaining))
                  << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
Sucessfully parsed message: 12345 and "SOMETHING IMPORTANT"
Remaining in buffer: 8 bytes
Buffer contents: "trailing"
```

Comment: Added an X3 parser example **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nsM4fxnb3)**

Comment: And updated to also show how to treat remaining buffer data: https://godbolt.org/z/jYsGev1TW

Answer (score 0):

well, recently i tried to pass some pic data in one process to another, I have tested them below:
Suppose you have data like this  `std::array<char, 6*1024*1024> curImg = xxxx`,
you just need to do this:
   `std::string picdata(std::begin(curImg.data()), std::end(curImg.data()));`
you will get your picdata, then you can convert it to `CV::MAT` , like this   `cv::Mat yuv422Img(height, width,CV_8UC2, (unsigned char*)picdata.c_str());`.